# The width of the widest character, relatively to the font settings

Tags: dimensions

I write a software that generates LaTeX code. For various reasons, I'd like to know the  width of the largest character, relatively to the current font settings.

As a developer, I wrote a Perl script that produces a LaTeX document (let us call it "**output.tex**"). This LaTeX document ("output.tex"), once processed through LuaLaTeX produces a files that contain the width (and other dimensions) of all characters (let use call it "output.dim").

> Please note that if you are interested in the Perl script, you can find it [here](https://github.com/denis-beurive/LaTeX/tree/master/lengths) (this is the file "char.pl").

The file "**output.tex**" looks like :

> Please note that I don't show here all the content of the file. I
>   removed some lines. You can get the full file on this [permanent
>   link](https://github.com/denis-beurive/LaTeX/blob/master/lengths/output.tex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{dimensions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.dim}{dimensions}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0px}

\begin{document}
   \newsavebox{\boxaaaa}
   \savebox{\boxaaaa}{\framebox{a}}
   \addtostream{dimensions}{a:  \the\wd\boxaaaa, \the\ht\boxaaaa, \the\dp\boxaaaa}

   \newsavebox{\boxbaaa}
   \savebox{\boxbaaa}{\framebox{b}}
   \addtostream{dimensions}{b:  \the\wd\boxbaaa, \the\ht\boxbaaa, \the\dp\boxbaaa}

   \newsavebox{\boxcaaa}
   \savebox{\boxcaaa}{\framebox{c}}
   \addtostream{dimensions}{c:  \the\wd\boxcaaa, \the\ht\boxcaaa, \the\dp\boxcaaa}

   % More lines...

   \newsavebox{\boxzzka}
   \savebox{\boxzzka}{\framebox{8}}
   \addtostream{dimensions}{8:  \the\wd\boxzzka, \the\ht\boxzzka, \the\dp\boxzzka}

   \newsavebox{\boxzzla}
   \savebox{\boxzzla}{\framebox{9}}
   \addtostream{dimensions}{9:  \the\wd\boxzzla, \the\ht\boxzzla, \the\dp\boxzzla}

\end{document}
```

The file "**output.dim**" looks like :

> Please note that I don't show here all the content of the file. I
>   removed some lines. You can get the full file on this [permanent
>   link](https://github.com/denis-beurive/LaTeX/blob/master/lengths/output.dim).

```
a: 5.8pt, 4.70554pt, 0.4pt
b: 6.35556pt, 7.34444pt, 0.4pt
c: 5.24443pt, 4.70554pt, 0.4pt
...
8: 5.8pt, 6.84444pt, 0.4pt
9: 5.8pt, 6.84444pt, 0.4pt
```

OK. So, using the content of the generated file "output.dim", I can get the dimensions of all characters for the given font settings. And, thus, I can get the maximum width of a character (a simple script would do the job).

This solution works... however, it is not elegant. You have to execute (Perl) scripts to get dimensions, and then you can produce a LaTeX document (through other scripts). Besides, all the calculations on dimensions should be handled by LaTeX.

Do you have a more elegant solution to get the width of the widest character, relatively to the current font settings ?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by “character”: does the em-dash count, for instance?

Comment: You don't need to box all your chars, you can use  eg. ``\the\fontcharwd\font`\w`` to get the width of the w. But beside this it really depends on what you mean by  "char".

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I call a "character" any "symbol" that can be used in a text (this includes accented characters, or mathematical symbols, although I did not mention it in my example).

Comment: as you are using lualatex you can use fonts with a lot (hundreds of thousands) of characters, do you really generate a list of all of them in perl?

Answer (score 3):

This is scalable: if not only alphanumerics are needed, just add to the initial list (accented characters should be braced for safety, so `{é}`, for instance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_beurive_alphabet_tl
 {
  0123456789
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 }

\box_new:N \l__beurive_widest_box
\dim_new:N \l__beurive_widest_dim
\tl_new:N \l__beurive_widest_tl
\tl_new:N \widestchar
\dim_new:N \widestcharwd

\NewDocumentCommand{\computewidest}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  #1 % optionally select a font
  \dim_zero:N \l__beurive_widest_dim
  \tl_clear:N \l__beurive_widest_tl
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_beurive_alphabet_tl
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__beurive_widest_box { ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l__beurive_widest_box > \l__beurive_widest_dim }
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l__beurive_widest_dim { \box_wd:N \l__beurive_widest_box }
      \tl_set:Nn \l__beurive_widest_tl { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \dim_gset_eq:NN \widestcharwd \l__beurive_widest_dim
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \widestchar \l__beurive_widest_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\computewidest
The widest character is ``\widestchar'', width \the\widestcharwd

\bigskip

\computewidest[\Large\bfseries\itshape]
The widest character is ``\widestchar'', width \the\widestcharwd

\bigskip

\computewidest[\ttfamily]
The widest character is ``\widestchar'', width \the\widestcharwd

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this example. I don't understand the code yet, but I will analyse it. I did not know that LaTeX can be used to write such algorithm.

Comment: @grep: I understand that you define variables and functions, and you use imperative programming control structure (branching, loops...). I also "guess" that you assign types to variables. Thus, I'd say that LaTeX is more than a markup language (like HTML). It is a markup language and a programming language that uses the imperative paradigm. OK, but where can I find documentation about the "programming language" feature ?

All I find is documentation about the use of LaTeX as a markup language. I found the TexBook. However, the TexBook does not mention some macro that you use

Comment: @DenisBeurive It's called `expl3` and is the base programming language for the future LaTeX3. Do `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3` for a start.

Comment: That's interesting. I tested your code with my installation of TexLive (v 6.2.1) which includes LuaLaTeX version beta-0.80.0. And it works. I thought that LaTeX V3 was not released yet (I heard about it on https://www.latex-project.org/latex3/). Thus, LaTeX 3 is already implemented (at least part of it). And we can already use it. Is it correct ?

Comment: @DenisBeurive The programming layer is quite stable now.